# Creating Radar Map on Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I have a response data from a Radar Layer API like this:

```
{
 "Date": "2020-04-18T04:00:05+03:00",
 "Source": 2,
 "Kml": [
  {
  "Polygons": [
    {
      "Polygon": [
        { "Cordinates": [25.8409, 51.6199] },
        { "Cordinates": [25.8341541, 51.619873] },
        { "Cordinates": [25.834177, 51.61238] },
        { "Cordinates": [25.8308582, 51.5936356] },
        { "Cordinates": [25.8275185, 51.5823822] }
        ....
        ....
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Color": "#47C247"
 },
 {
  "Polygons": [
    {
      "Polygon": [
        { "Cordinates": [26.1740189, 50.5239372] },
        { "Cordinates": [26.1841354, 50.5238838] },
        { "Cordinates": [26.1909122, 50.53136] },
        { "Cordinates": [26.1977215, 50.5463562] }
        ....
        ....
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Color": "#47C247"
 },
 ...
 ...
```

I want to create a Radar map using this data.

I tried to create polygons using each data and created a set interval function to loop through each polygon for 250ms so that it acts as an animation.

```
setInterval(() => {
        deleteAllShape();
                // console.log(data);
                data.Kml.map((polygons) => {
                    const shape = polygons.Polygons.map((polygon) => {
                        const newMapData = [];
                        polygon.Polygon.map((obj) => {
                            const path = { lat: obj.Cordinates[0], lng: 
                                   obj.Cordinates[1] };
                                 newMapData.push(path);
                        });
                        poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                            paths: newMapData,
                            strokeColor: polygons.Color,
                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 0,
                            fillColor: polygons.Color,
                            fillOpacity: 0.35,
                            draggable: false,
                            editable: false,
                        });
                        poly.setMap(map);
                        allPolygons.push(poly);
                    });
                });
    },250)
    function deleteAllShape() {
      poly = null;
      for (let i = 0; i < allPolygons.length; i++) {
          allPolygons[i].setMap(null);
           }
       }
```

[image: Radar Image]

This is working to an extend. But the problem is the map and the browser slows down and hangs up after creating some polygons.

When I researched on several radar maps (eg: windy.com) :-
[image]

I found that they are rendering images on the map. My question is how to create images using above data and create a radar map?

Comment: "the map and the browser slows down and hangs up after creating some polygons" - what does your javascript look like that's creating the polygons?  Please add it to your question. I suspect "a set interval function to loop through each polygon for 250ms" is causing any slowdown.

Comment: @duncan I've added the setInterval portion of my code in the question. I think there might be some memory leaks happening which cause the hanging of the map. But as per my research polygons are not used for creating a radar map, Images as layers are used to create a radar map. Please provide a most appropriate solution for better performance.

Comment: try printing to the console the total number of polygons in `allPolygons` after each interval, I think they are still there, and on every new interval, the `for` to unlink them from the map has to process them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not answer your question, as I'm unclear what you're trying to do with images instead of polygons.  However, it might speed things up.

Currently you loop over `allPolygons` every 250ms, preventing all previous polygons from appearing on the map.
Then you draw a new polygon, and add it into allPolygons, so it gets removed on the next iteration in 250ms.  That's all fine.

However, as the number of polygons increase, you'll be increasing the size of that for loop each time:

```
for (let i = 0; i < allPolygons.length; i++) {
```

So it'll get progressively slower as you draw more polygons.  You don't say how many polygons you're adding, but I'd guess it's a lot.

Instead, all you need to do is hide the most recently created polygon.  All the previous ones in allPolygons will already have been hidden, so you don't need to call `setMap(null)` on every polygon, as it's just the most recent one that's not already set to `null`.

Maybe something like:

```
function deleteAllShape() {
    allPolygons[allPolygons.length - 1].setMap(null);
}
```

Alternatively, just this, if you don't need `allPolygons` for anything else, save you having to store them in that array.

```
poly.setMap(null);
```

Also, instead of creating `poly` then calling `poly.setMap(map);`, just do

```
poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: newMapData,
    strokeColor: polygons.Color,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillColor: polygons.Color,
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    draggable: false,
    editable: false,
    map
});
```

Comment: Thank you for finding the time to answer in detail. The problem was like You and Germanio said, the allPolygons array was keeping on increasing. But unfortunately, the codes you give are not working. So I tried forcefully emptying the array after each interval and it's working perfectly without any hang or slow down. Thanks for the hint.